# ArcGIS REST API query failing with large geometry as input

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, web-service, rest, request

I am querying different ArcGIS Services passing a polygon as the input geometry to get the features from the service that intersect with it. However, depending on the polygon's geometry I get sometimes the following error when attempting to do the query:

```
Server Error
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Doing tests with different polygons I realized that the query failed when the polygon's geometry was too large, regardless of the service being queried. For example, a query with a polygon composed of 11 vertices worked fine but one with a polygon composed 65 vertices failed. All tests were carried out in the ArcGIS REST interface (using Chrome), in Python (using `requests`) and Postman, yielding the same results.

Reading the ArcGIS REST API documentation was not helpful as it does not specify whether there is a character limit in the input geometry.

How can I query an ArcGIS Service using a long geometry as one of the inputs?

Comment: All web servers have a limit on URL content. Coordinates should always be submitted in a POST, both for privacy and for data volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by changing the request method from `GET` to `POST`. Given the [difference between these two methods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/listtutorial/Difference-between-GET-and-POST-method-in-HTTP/3916), it makes sense that using `GET` to do the query including large geometries as input results in an error (as the input parameters are appended to the URL rather than to the body of the request).

> [...] Main difference between POST and GET method is that GET carries
>   request parameter appended in URL string while POST carries request
>   parameter in message body [...]